# Reverse Hangman

Tags: riddle, english, letters

> Add "g", and I may end early in the morning.
>   Add "b", and I may end late in the afternoon.
>   Add "t", and you better listen while you do it.
>   Add "y", and it can come in a bundle.

Answers should be in the form

> _ndroid

followed by your explanation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Answer : JO_
>
>  JO**G** - people generally prefer jogging early in the morning
>  JO**B** - work started in the morning may take up entire afternoon
>  JO**T** - while noting down important details from boss/teacher they expect us to pay attention to what they are saying
>  JO**Y** - new born baby is also referred to as a bundle of joy

Comment: strange! somebody downvoted this answer

Comment: btw you should give the answer (without the given (bold) letters) with an underscore instead of the missing letter as requested in the question

Comment: @somebody, you are missing the point

Comment: I know (I didn't downvote btw) but you should still include it

Comment: Nicely done! +1 and accepted

Comment: @lois6b :| I didn't mean like that I meant like `<rest of word>_` at the start of the answer